# What to do if I get "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]"

Tags: transactions, gas, out-of-gas, fees, ledger-nano-s

Hoping someone can help me,I(ve sent some ETH from my Nano S to Poloniex, and it didn't go through. Etherscan says:

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]. The
>   value shows "Cancelled".

I think the transaction is supposed to be cancelled and the ETH returned less the gas fee, but the ETH isn't showing on my Nano.
I'd appreciate any help in trying to figure out how to either push the transaction with more gas or have the ETH returned.

Comment: You're right with everything you said. Except I believe your nano is not connected to internet so it can't know the transaction failed and assumed it went well. I'd recommand you to check on etherscan your address to check your balance.

Comment: Thanks--I did that and it shows the tx started, but was cancelled because of the gas issue.  But the ETH didn't return to the Nano.  Any idea how that can be completed?

Comment: Maybe this answer is relevant? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17229/transaction-failed-due-to-out-of-gas-how-can-i-get-refund?rq=1

Comment: @AjoyBhatia you should have entered your comment as an answer as I believe it's very helpful.

Comment: Good to know that it helped you, @peteski22. I am not sure if it was the answer to the OP's issue. And I'm not sure if a link to another answer can be posted as an answer in itself.

Answer (score 2):

If your transaction runs out of gas it will be marked as CANCELLED and the ether will never leave your account. You can try checking for the transaction on a web based block viewer like http://www.etherscan.io.

It also sounds like the hardware wallet implementation could use a bit of an update to detect issues like that and update more quickly.