# Transaction failed due to "out of gas", how can I get refund?

Tags: gas, out-of-gas

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf0d9a39afef87aab8072876dbdeb1a4c8818dee20e13e6c57a13d8fa2a640985

My transaction from okcoin to another exchange failed because out of gas.
When I contact okcoin, they said they need to wait till the ETH "completely return to their sending wallet", but this transaction happened 4 days before and got 19000 confirmations, how is it possible that still not returned to their wallet?

Can anyone tell me if this error occurred, the ETH is immediately returned, or it need a few days? and is there a way I can check whether the amount has been returned?  I suppose there will not be a new transaction created on the blockchain for this particular return, so how can I track it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Ether from a failed transaction actually never leaves your wallet in any way. If the tx failed, the ETH were not sent. So it's in OKCoins rather new, seemingly not yet fully functional implementation of ethereum. So yes, "wait till the ETH completely return to the(ir) sending wallet" is total nonsense. You should see your ETH in your account still, as it never left OKCoin.